# A double and even riddle

Tags: riddle, word

The answer to the following riddle is a 12-letter word.

- My 1, 12, 8, 6, 9, 10, 4, 5 is a traveller in space.
- My 9, 10, 12, 6, 3, 11, 5 was the last word of Charles.
- My 5,  4,  12,  8,  11,  9,  3 is something that you should not do.
- My 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 9, 6 is a combination of things.
- My whole can be double-dealing or even-handed.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> AMBIDEXTROUS

My 1, 12, 8, 6, 9, 10, 4, 5 is a traveller in space.

> ASTEROID

My 9, 10, 12, 6, 3, 11, 5 was the last word of Charles.

> ROSEBUD (From Citizen Kane, not King Charles I. This confused me for a while.)

My 5, 4, 12, 8, 11, 9, 3 is something that you should not do.

> DISTURB

My 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 9, 6 is a combination of things.

> MIXTURE

My whole can be double-??????? or even-??????.

> Doublehanded and Evenhanded are synonyms for or related to ambidextrous. Evenhanded means "not favoring one side over the other". Doublehanded means having or using 2 hands, or requiring the use of 2 hands. (All praise to Nate Kerkhofs)

Comment: Double-??????? means double-dealing, but even-?????? means something else (I can't find it). These are both synonyms for the answer.

Comment: Even-handed maybe?

Comment: Doublehanded and Evenhanded are synonyms for or related to ambidextrous. Evenhanded means "not favoring one side over the other". doublehanded means having or using 2 hands, or requiring the use of 2 hands.